# Open CV Line Detection

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

[Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCYa.jpg)

I need to detect the path the tractor can take between the crops and after several preprocessing steps i ended up with this image.Now i need to find the crop rows or if not I need to find the center line between the crops.I tried Hough transform and linefit methods but none of them are giving me good results.Can someone help me with this.I have attached a sample image I am working with

Comment: you could add your code and expected result.

Comment: Can you add your original image and code to produce the results?  Your results are not reproducible and is highly likely that your question will be closed due to non-reproducible results.  Please take the [tour] first and also visit [ask].